How can I change the time data format in the DataFrame column?
Good day! I have a dataframe.
It has a column with data. This data is presented in the following format - (8 p.m.; 10 a.m. and others).
It only contains objects in the time format.
But I can't convert the data to another format like - (20:00. 10:00).
How can I do something?
I did something similar with difficulty - but with data that has the date format.
How can I do something - but with the time format?
tbpoteri['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tbpoteri.date)
tbpoteri['date'] = tbpoteri['date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

i = 0
for k in range(len(tbpoteri)):
    valuetime = str(tbpoteri.at[i, 'time'])
    tbpoteri.at[i, 'time'] = pd.to_datetime(valuetime)
    i = i + 1

tbpoteri['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tbpoteri.time).dt.time
tbpoteri['time'] = tbpoteri['time'].strftime('%H:%M')


Hi! Please add a [mre]. E.g., use df.to_dict() and tweak the result to create a minimal sample of your df. Also add the expected output based on the provided sample.

Taking literally the only described data, a.m./p.m. aren't supported for datetime parsing, so convert to a supported string and you could parse as:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['8 a.m.', '10 p.m.']})
print(df)
df.time = df.time.str.replace('a.m.', 'AM')
df.time = df.time.str.replace('p.m.', 'PM')
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%I %p').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
print(df)

Output:
      time
0   8 a.m.
1  10 p.m.
    time
0  08:00
1  22:00

